# How to reset default app in Android Things OS?

Tags: android-things

Yesterday I started an Android Things project and I was testing the app using Android Studio. In order to connect to the device using `adb.exe`, I used the IP of the android device that I saw on the default OS's app (the starting screen). So, after the yesterday's testing it seems that my app is now the default app even if I don't have it connected to the PC.

The problem is that now I cannot see the device's IP address so I can connect to it using `adb.exe`.

Is there a way of going back to the default OS's app?

PS. The only solution I found is re-installing the Android Things OS.

Comment: You might make use of the script for uninstalling the apps as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41127331/android-things-intent-for-boot/41538324#41538324).

Comment: Alternate solution is to use download app from play store that displays connected devices on wifi network.
I Used FING

Comment: If your only objective is to find back the IP of your Android Things device, it would be simpler to use the ARP table. No need to uninstall anything or install anything, one command for Linux/Windows system `arp -a`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To go back to default android thing logo screen.Uninstall the  app using

```
adb uninstall <pkg name>
```

If you want to connect to AT without knowing ip use following command

```
adb connect Android.local
```

Also you can use serial cable to find ip of AT.

If you install multiple apps.AT will ask for your choice as below
[image]

Answer (score 4):

uninstall the app using adb

```
adb uninstall <package-name>
```

if you have connected a keyboard to the raspberry pi board, you can go to the home screen by pressing escape button

Answer (score 3):

(I don't have enough reputation to comment so I make an answer, sorry)

If you want to know the IP of your Raspeberry from your computer, you can use the [ARP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) table.

From Ubuntu/Linux or Windows, just type `arp -a`

Your Android Things device will appear in this list with its IP !

Comment: this is so delicious

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to uninstall your app, you can just close it:

```
adb shell am force-stop <package-name>
```

and of course you can close it from your app:

```
this.finish();
```

Also you can show your ip address in your app if you have screen. For me **adb connect Android.local** doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to log into your router and see all of the connected devices and pull the ip address from there. Really easy with Google Wifi